# How do I get a multi-display virgl 3D accelerated QEMU VM on a NVIDIA card in virt-manager?

Tags: linux, qemu, libvirt, nvidia, virt-manager

I've managed to get virgl 3D acceleration running in QEMU/KVM, and now I want to see if I can get it running with multiple displays. However when I add more heads to the Video Device Display 1 is mirrored onto the other displays rather than extended, no matter what I do with the settings. Does anyone know how to to get this working? I can't do GPU passthrough as my CPU doesn't have integrated graphics, and I don't have the space or the budget for another GPU.

## Host Machine

| OS | Arch |
| --- | --- |
| Desktop | KDE |
| Display Server | x11 |
| CPU | AMD Ryzen 7 5800X3D |
| GPU | NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4090 |
| RAM | 64GB |

## Guest Machine

| OS | BigLinux |
| --- | --- |
| Desktop | KDE |
| Display Server | x11 |

## How I got virgl working with NVIDIA

1. I set up the VM normally through virt-manager's wizard.
2. I installed the ISO, then shut the VM down after loading the desktop on the installed system.
3. In Details view, with XML editing enabled in virt-manager:

   1. Under `Video Virtio` I enable 3D acceleration.
   2. Under `Display Spice` I set `Listen type` to `None` and leave `OpenGL` unchecked. (I have found leaving `Listen type` as `Address` works too, but both the tutorial I followed for this and the warning that comes up when you enable OpenGL tell me to leave it as `None`, so I do)
   3. Under `Overview` I switch to the XML tab

      1. I delete `<gl/>` from the existing `<graphics/>` device if it exists.
      2. Below the existing `<graphics/>` device I add the following:

```
    <graphics type="egl-headless">
      <gl rendernode="/dev/dri/renderD128"/>
    </graphics>
```

Now when I start the VM, I open Lutris and under Preferences I check Hardware Information, and it shows that virgl is working and lists my GPU.

## What I did to add more displays to the VM

1. After enabling virgl with the above steps, I shut down the VM.
2. I go to Details, and under `Video Virtio`'s XML tab I change the `heads` value to `3`, because I want 3 displays.
3. After booting the VM to desktop, I enter `virt-viewer -a` in a terminal on the host to launch it in attach mode. (With `Listen type` set to `Address` I have the option to launch it normally or use remote-viewer instead)
4. To initialise the extra displays, from the first display window (which should be initialised) I check and uncheck one of the additional displays.

## Weird details about the results of those steps

The displays are automatically arranged to be side, but what I see is an imperfect mirror of Display 1 on the other displays - the other displays only seem to update when something changes, and then not always.
Despite showing Display 1, the other displays do at least act like I want them to behind what's displayed; I can test this by arranging the display windows next to each other on the host, dragging a window between the displays on the guest and then dragging where the titlebar should be on the extra display.